# RavenDB best practice for 'select all'?

Tags: linq, select, ravendb

I've got a question on how to implement the same behavior of "select * from xxx where ... " on RavenDB, given that there will be a huge number of documents returned (index already set up).

I heard that the default behavior is Take(128), right? But what I want is something like TakeAll() because I don't know the actual number. How to achieve that properly?

What I can think of is to use Skip() and Take() until coming to the end. But this looks really tedious for such a simple requirement. In addition, it may exceed the request number limit for a single session, which is another barrier that I wonder how to gracefully overcome.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you end up using `Skip()` and `Take()`, don't forget that RavenDB has 'safe by default' mechanisms in place to only allow X queries per DocumentSession.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dodd, the reason for that is, that it is *always* bad practice to load all at once, no matter what you're trying to do. However, by default you can fetch 1024 at once using .Take(1024). If you *really* want to increase this limit, you can change the "Raven/MaxPageSize" at the server-configuration, which defaults to 1024, but again - you hardly want to do this.

Comment: In my senario, basically we need to iterate through all the job items (consider a million-sized url pool for a crawler) and process them. Of course I won't keep them in memory but I do need go over each of them like a stream. Any proposal?

Comment: Do this in batches of 1024 is the best way I can think of. Going this approach you ensure that your memory keeps manageable and you also don't need to mody ravens configuration

Comment: Got it~ 2 things to confirm: (1) I need to open multiple sessions to do that (2) The last Take(1024) will successfully return even if there is fewer than 1024 left. Is that right?

Comment: @DanielLang You say it's *always* bad practice to bring all of the documents over. But what about a scenario where the documents are the data source for a chart, and we need tens of thousands of these to serve as the data points for the chart? Is there any other way than getting them all at once?

Answer (score 1):

Dodd, while I agree with @Daniel that it isn't best practice to *select all*, you still may have a good use case for it.

### **EDIT:**

**This technique will not work as the `MaxPageSize` will still be the upper bound (as noted by @Ayende in comments below.**

<strike>Rather than setting the `MaxPageSize` or calling `Take()` in a loop iteration, you can do two simple queries to get the data.</strike>

The first query will be used to determine **HOW MANY** records exist. Notice the `Take(0)` which doesn't return any of the results, but it will populate the *statistics*.

```
RavenQueryStatistics stats = null;
var tempPagingQuery = (from p in session.Query<Page>
                        .Statistics(out stats)
                       select p).Take(0).FirstOrDefault();
```

The second query will be fetching all of the records. Here we use `TotalResults` from the *statistics* that was gathered above.

```
pages = (from p in session.Query<Page>
         select p).Take(stats.TotalResults).ToList();
```

Comment: Adam, that won't work. We limit the MaxPageSize explicitly, if you try to pass a size that is bigger than that, we will limit it to the MaxPagesize.

Comment: Thanks for the information @AyendeRahien. I remember seeing this technique on the google group somewhere and I adopted it for our MVC routing table. It does seem like there should be a way to overcome the limit without changing the MaxPageSize variable. For example if I want to load all info from Pages that are stored as individual documents in order to build up the MVC Routing Table, I'd have to loop an **unknown X times** making an **unknown Y trips** to the DB to get all of the data. Surely there is a better way that would allow me to get ALL of the data?

Comment: Adam, thank you anyway. Yes, as I mentioned in my question, I know Skip() and Take() will do. But I am asking if there is a safe TakeAll() which returns an IEnumerable (not in memory, like a FileStream) which wraps all the SkipAndTakeAndBuffer magic underneath. That will make our life a lot easier. @AyendeRahien Thanks.